# Ошибка типа данных: "ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type"

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3, discord, type-error

Есть столбец `guildToken` типа `TEXT`, и пытаюсь получить из него значение:

```
pyguild = (ctx.guild.id,)
cur.execute(
    "SELECT guildToken FROM guildsConfig WHERE guildID == ?", (ctx.guild.id))
token = cur.fetchall()
```

В итоге, ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Максим\Desktop\HelperBotForDiscord-master\helper.py", line 163, in checkDB
    print(cur.execute(
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

Comment: Попробуйте `cur.execute("SELECT guildToken FROM guildsConfig WHERE guildID == ?", (str(ctx.guild.id)))`

Comment: в SQL стандарте - оператор равенства состоит из __единственного__ знака равенства

Answer (score 8, accepted):

у вас сразу две ошибки -  двойной знак равенства вместо одинарного и вы передали в качестве параметров скаляр вместо кортежа или списка:

Попробуйте так:

```
cur.execute(
    "SELECT guildToken FROM guildsConfig WHERE guildID = ?", (ctx.guild.id, ))
# ERRORs: ---------------------------------------------^  ----------------^^
```

PS обратите внимание на запятую после ctx.guild.id - благодаря ней в скобках передаётся кортеж. Если ее убрать, то передаваться будет скалярное значение.

Comment: Приношу свои извинения, спасибо вам большое за ответ